# Why didn't Doctor Strange restore Tony Stark after he used the Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame* Tony Stark makes use of the Stones, taking a great amount of damage doing so. Is there a reason why Doctor Strange did not use the Time Stone to restore Tony in the same way [he restored an apple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiEoxQp4DhQ)?

Comment: [Asked and answered over at Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99671/63559). (and on a bunch of other sites, as well...)

Comment: Speculation, but if the damage was caused by Snapping, then presumably undoing the damage would require undoing the Snap as well, and that would be bad.

Comment: Any and all answers to “Why didn’t they do this in Endgame?” Is- “that was one of the 14,000,604 outcomes that didn’t work”

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Good point. The time stone can partially rewind time, or loop time, or.. something else? They also have the Reality Stone. Could it have been used in conjunction with the Time Stone to restore him?

Comment: Why didn’t Wanda grab the gauntlet and bring Vision back? Maybe she [didn’t need to](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WandaVision).

Comment: Wibbly wobbly timey wimey...

Comment: Tony Stark is not an apple.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A similar event happens during the course of *Doctor Strange* with the Ancient One. Just like Strange, she looks through time and sees countless possible futures with countless different events playing out, but cannot find any in which she survives her battle with Kaecilius.

> I’ve spent so many years peering through time, looking at this exact moment. But I can’t see past it. I’ve prevented countless terrible futures. And after each one, there’s always another. And they all lead here, but never further.

To me, this would indicate that there are events which are, to put it simply, destined to happen, and cannot be undone even with the Time Stone. The Ancient One was always going to die in battle with Kaecilius, and Tony Stark was always going to die defeating Thanos. The Time Stone's exact workings are somewhat vague, but this aspect seems consistent.

Comment: Perhaps reversing time on Tony Stark would un-snap Thanos and his army?

Comment: I think the phrase you are looking for is "fixed point in time".

Comment: @DJClayworth Also: "A big ball of wibbly wobbly, timey wimey stuff."

Answer (score 18):

The Russos answered this question previously and it is because any scenario where Tony is saved means Thanos will win in the long run, his death is a must. No mention is made of how Thanos would win if Tony is saved.

> **Q: In IW, Thanos used the time stone to reverse the time so he could [sic (revive?)] the already dead Vision, and it didn’t cause any time parallax. Why did no one use time stone to save Iron Man’s life in EG?**
>
> A: It’s because even if you save Iron Man, it will still not change the fact that Thanos will eventually win the war. Among the 14 million possibilities that Doctor Strange has seen, Iron Man’s sacrifice is a must for that one win scenario.
>
> <sub>[BGR, ‘Avengers: Endgame’ directors just explained some of the movie’s biggest mysteries](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/)</sub>

Comment: Great. He must make a sacrifice. He did. So did the apple. What's to stop the damage from being lethal or permanent?

Comment: @Underverse Clearly if his sacrifice is reversed that means that Thanos can somehow win down the road. It is not elaborated upon how that will happen.

Comment: In other words, it's a cop-out.

Comment: @Adamant not exactly. In the other answer if you undo what killed Tony (which is what the time stone would do), you undo the snap (as that's what killed Tony). If the snap is undone, then Thanos and his forces are back. So he literally can't be brought back by the time stone because if he is, so are Thanos and his forces.

Comment: There was an example of how the Time Stone does its thing all the way back in *Doctor Strange*. When Strange and Mordo arrive in Hong Kong, Strange finds Wong dead. Strange simply doesn't bring Wong back to life, he has to literally undo the events to the point before he was killed by rewinding time, and then stop or interrupt the event that killed him the first time. Thus, as pointed out by others, why he can't save Stark; Stark has to snap his fingers to defeat Thanos, but since that's what also kills him, you can't undo one without also undoing the other.

Comment: @KeithMorrison I kinda disagree. In the apple scene the effect to the apple getting eaten and decaying could be reversed without the cause (Doctor Strange) going back in time. Another example is the scene where Doctor Strange gave Thor some beer. The effect (beer getting drank) could be undone without the cause (Thor drinking) being reversed. Thor would of course not like it if he would loose all the beer in his tummy. In the same way, the effect (Ironman dying) could have been undone without the cause (snap) also being undone.

Comment: @DVX First nothing confirms that the eaten apple remained in his stomach. Second, who says he used the Time Stone to serve beer? That would be the hight of reckless frivolity.

Comment: There's also some precedent that the stones can't be used to undo the sacrifices made for the stones (eg Black Widow). It'd be kind of silly if destroying half the universe cost the use of your arm, but you could then just immediately heal it with the same gauntlet that caused the damage.

Answer (score 15):

Petersaber mentioned this in a comment, but I'd like to expand on it:

Reversing time to undo Tony's death would also undo the outcome of the event that led to his death—his Snap.  In order to save Tony, you have to rewind to before he snapped, which puts Thanos and his whole army back, which ultimately solves nothing.

Remember how in *Infinity War*, when Wanda destroyed the Mind Stone, the explosion caused a massive shockwave that rattled all the trees in the area?  When Thanos used the Time Stone to reverse that explosion, we saw the shock and the trees move in reverse.  You can't undo one event without undoing the other stuff attached to it.